# Angular 16 - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: angular

Angular 16 - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The injectable 'FileSaverService' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "psboleto",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.4",
    "export-from-json": "^1.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-filesaver": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^16.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.3/xlsx-0.19.3.tgz",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "export-from-json": "1.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}
```

I unistall e reinstall node.modules but nothing work

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `ngx-filesaver` to a recent version, as version 8.x is outdated and not supported in Angular 16.

In particular, the `ngcc` or *Angular Compatibility Compiler* has been removed in Angular 16, meaning that libraries that we built with Angular version 11 and older can no longer be used.